# Setting ImageIcon for Java application in Netbeans returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, netbeans, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to set the ImageIcon for a java application, but when I try to obtain the resource I receive a NullPointerException.

This is the directory structure inside of Netbeans:

- project-name

  - resources
    -images
    icon.png
  - src
  - target

Here is the code I'm using to set the ImageIcon:

```
protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path, String description) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
    } else {
        LOG.error("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've inserted the following custom code for the iconImage property in Netbeans:

```
Form.setIconImage(createImageIcon("/project-name/resources/images/icon.png", "Icon Description").getImage());
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have u set `Resources` as Resources folder in NetBeans?

Comment: Not sure why the directory structure came out that way but there is an "images" folder nested inside the resources directory. I have also tried cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: @ThomasBanderas I have not specifically set Resources as a Resources folder. How do I do that? Thanks.                                                                                                                     Also, I have tried placing the resources folder inside the src folder.

Comment: This question was originally closed as a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it because someone saw the words "NullPointerException" and assumed it was a duplicate. I reopened the question because the question is about "how to read a resource file" when using Netbeans.

Comment: `Form.setIconImage(createImageIcon("/icon.png", "Icon Description").getImage());`